# How to inflate custom layout file using RemoteViews in android?

Tags: android

I am using firebase messaging service class to get notification and i want to inflate custom layout for my incoming notification but when i am using RemoteViews() constructor in android side then it can't be able to access my layout file here.can anyone can tell me how to do it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdSbI.png)

Comment: try File-> Invalidate caches/ Restart

Comment: i have done this many times but it did not work

Comment: just click on that red line where you got the error and press Alt+Enter, see what you got

Comment: i got rename refernce ,intoduce local variable options only

Comment: what is displays when type R.layout. ??

Comment: check the import for `R`. It should not be from `android` also post relevant code.